Javascript AST to yaml
I have a requirement where I want to convert all my javascript files to yml format. Tried all the open source libs, nothing worked. Tried implementing myself, but due to the nature of nodes, always stuck in different issues.
Looking to finally convert all my codebase to yml format like this :
spec:
  title: Employee
  display: shell
  authorization:
    allowAll: true
  content:
    - component: Text
      name: text
      props:
        value: Employee Details Page
        variant: h2
    - component: Image
      name: image
      props:
        src: https://example.png
    - component: TextField
      name: textField
      props:
        size: medium
        isRequired: true
        minLength: 3
        fullWidth: true
        label: Employee Name
    - component: TextField
      name: textField10
      props:
        size: medium
        isRequired: true
        minLength: 0
        fullWidth: true
        label: Employee Age
    - component: TextField
      name: textField9
      props:
        size: medium
        isRequired: true
        minLength: 3
        fullWidth: true
        label: Last Company Name
    - component: TextField
      name: textField8
      props:
        size: medium
        isRequired: true
        minLength: 3
        fullWidth: true
        label: Current CTC
    - component: TextField
      name: textField7
      props:
        size: medium
        isRequired: true
        minLength: 3
        fullWidth: true
        label: Expected CTC
    - component: Button
      name: button
      props:
        size: large
        variant: contained
        fullWidth: true
        content: Submit
      layout:
        horizontalAlign: center

Here's how the sample js code for the same looks like
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { TextField, Button, Typography } from '@mui/material';

const EmployeePage = () => {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    employeeName: '',
    employeeAge: '',
    lastCompanyName: '',
    currentCTC: '',
    expectedCTC: ''
  });

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setFormData({
      ...formData,
      [name]: value
    });
  };

  const handleSubmit = () => {
    // Logic for form submission
    console.log('Submitted Data:', formData);
  };

  return (
    <div style={styles.container}>
      {/* Page Title */}
      <Typography variant="h2" component="h2">
        Employee Details Page
      </Typography>

      {/* Image */}
      <img src="https://example.png" alt="Employee" style={styles.image} />

      {/* Form Fields */}
      <TextField
        label="Employee Name"
        name="employeeName"
        value={formData.employeeName}
        onChange={handleChange}
        required
        fullWidth
        variant="outlined"
        size="medium"
        style={styles.textField}
        inputProps={{ minLength: 3 }}
      />
      
      <TextField
        label="Employee Age"
        name="employeeAge"
        value={formData.employeeAge}
        onChange={handleChange}
        required
        fullWidth
        variant="outlined"
        size="medium"
        style={styles.textField}
      />

      <TextField
        label="Last Company Name"
        name="lastCompanyName"
        value={formData.lastCompanyName}
        onChange={handleChange}
        required
        fullWidth
        variant="outlined"
        size="medium"
        style={styles.textField}
        inputProps={{ minLength: 3 }}
      />

      <TextField
        label="Current CTC"
        name="currentCTC"
        value={formData.currentCTC}
        onChange={handleChange}
        required
        fullWidth
        variant="outlined"
        size="medium"
        style={styles.textField}
        inputProps={{ minLength: 3 }}
      />

      <TextField
        label="Expected CTC"
        name="expectedCTC"
        value={formData.expectedCTC}
        onChange={handleChange}
        required
        fullWidth
        variant="outlined"
        size="medium"
        style={styles.textField}
        inputProps={{ minLength: 3 }}
      />

      {/* Submit Button */}
      <Button
        variant="contained"
        size="large"
        fullWidth
        onClick={handleSubmit}
        style={styles.button}
      >
        Submit
      </Button>
    </div>
  );
};

const styles = {
  container: {
    width: '500px',
    margin: 'auto',
    padding: '20px',
    textAlign: 'center'
  },
  image: {
    width: '100%',
    height: 'auto',
    marginBottom: '20px'
  },
  textField: {
    marginBottom: '20px'
  },
  button: {
    marginTop: '20px'
  }
};

export default EmployeePage;


That's not a JavaScript AST. You can look at what an AST looks like at https://astexplorer.net/ .
Could you go a few steps back and explain what your source looks like, what you need, and why you need it?

Added the relevant details. Trying to build similar to mui toolpad.

Please explain why you want to do this, because I can't think of a use-case. Unless you mean you want to use YAML for data, e.g. you want to use YAML instead of JSON. Which is not the same as JavaScript.
